# Forgot Password with Ajax

Tags: ajax, forgot-password

Is there anyway to implement Forgot Password with Ajax. I tried the [Authenticate](https://www.objectivehtml.com/authenticate) 
but it doesn't working properly with EE v2.7+. Could anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably load in http://ee-zoo.com/docs/visitor/examples/forgot_password.html dynamically with Ajax into another template with relative ease.

Perhaps you could adjust http://ee-zoo.com/docs/visitor/examples/login_ajax.html and call it in at an appropriate time.

If that's not quite right for you, could you clarify what you're after with the ajax implementation? It's a little ambiguous at the mo.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. Is there any other way except Zoo Visitor. Please let me know.